# Can I digitally sign VBA code project using Apache POI?

Tags: java, vba, apache-poi, pfx

According to the upcoming changes with VBA sign (required by Microsoft) we have to be able to sign VBA Project with Apache POI. I was unable to find any information about this topic. Is it possible?